# Can i use getrect function with surf(X,Y,Z) plot?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, surface

Can i use `getrect` function in a `surf(X,Y,Z)` plot to get data only in a specified surface? Pratically, i want to do a rectangular selection for example  in Y-Z surface.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot use `getrect` in 3D. What is your expected output?

Comment: i want  a four-element vector with the form [ymin zmin width height]

Comment: So you just want the user to select a range of y and z values?

Comment: yes, Is there an alternative way to do it?